# Postgres group by and extract groups with more than one element

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to "group by" ver two unicode fields (keyword_text and keyword_match_type) and extract all columns and all rows for the groups which have more than two elements.

For example one row is:

```
keyword_text | keyword_norm | keyword_GAD_id| keyword_account  | keyword_MCC_id | keyword_campaign | keyword_campaign_GAD_id | keyword_ad_group | keyword_ad_group_GAD_id| keyword_destination_url | keyword_max_cpc | keyword_status | keyword_match_type | keyword_campaign_status | keyword_ad_group_status | db_id | created_at |
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"lebanese home delivery jai", "lebanese home delivery jai", 61557127036, "IN [S_02] Cuisine", 7795189055, "IN-JAI[S[Cui_30_EN]: Lebanese", 301573516, "IN-JAI[S[Cui_30_EN|del_02|geo_01]_ex: (Lebanese) Lebanese home delivery Jaipur", 11043049036, http://www.bla.in/restaurants/index/cuisines/lebanese/city/jaipur, 480000, ENABLED, EXACT, PAUSED, PAUSED, 1, "2014-07-18 18:42:43"
```

while the table was created with:

```
CREATE TABLE adword_keywords
(
  keyword_text character varying(1000) NOT NULL,
  keyword_norm character varying(1000) NOT NULL,
  "keyword_GAD_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  keyword_account character varying NOT NULL,
  "keyword_MCC_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  keyword_campaign character varying NOT NULL,
  "keyword_campaign_GAD_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  keyword_ad_group character varying NOT NULL,
  "keyword_ad_group_GAD_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  keyword_destination_url character varying NOT NULL,
  keyword_max_cpc double precision,
  keyword_status keyword_status,
  keyword_match_type match_type,
  keyword_campaign_status keyword_c_status,
  keyword_ad_group_status keyword_ag_status,
  db_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT adword_keywords_pkey PRIMARY KEY (db_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX ix_adword_keywords_keyword_norm
  ON adword_keywords
  USING btree
  (keyword_norm COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I tryied the following query:

```
SELECT adword_keywords.*
FROM adword_keywords 
    JOIN (
        SELECT adword_keywords.keyword_text AS keyword_text,adword_keywords.keyword_match_type AS keyword_match_type 
        FROM adword_keywords GROUP BY adword_keywords.keyword_text, adword_keywords.keyword_match_type 
        HAVING count(adword_keywords.db_id) > 1) AS anon_1 
    ON adword_keywords.keyword_text = anon_1.keyword_text AND adword_keywords.keyword_match_type = anon_1.keyword_match_type 
WHERE adword_keywords.keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED' AND adword_keywords.keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED' AND adword_keywords.keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
```

Unfortunately this returns the wrong result. Meaning also groups composed by one element (when groping over ['keyword_text','match_type'] )  !

Does anybody have an idea of what is groing wrong with this query?

Note that if I extract all data from database and put it in pandas datastructure with the folloiwing query:

```
SELECT * FROM adword_keywords  
WHERE adword_keywords.keyword_campaign_status = \'ENABLED\' 
AND adword_keywords.keyword_ad_group_status = \'ENABLED\' 
AND adword_keywords.keyword_status = \'ENABLED\'
```

I can filter the group which I would like to have as such:

```
df.groupy(['keyword_text','match_type']).filter(lambda x: x.shape[0]>1)
```

This latter procedure returns the correct results.

However, I would like to do the same with an sql query for performance and memory issue reasons (the dataset is huge cannot be fully load into RAM).

## EDIT

Based on the aswer of ypercube I there are three alternative queries which returns the correct result. I have collected them for reference with their running time: the first version is the fastest.

Using `EXISTS`, `1 loops, best of 3: 2.22 s per loop`:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM adword_keywords  
    WHERE keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED' 
      AND keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED' 
      AND keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
  )
SELECT a.*
FROM cte AS a
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cte AS b
        WHERE (b.keyword_text, b.keyword_match_type) 
            = (a.keyword_text, a.keyword_match_type)
          AND b.db_id <> a.db_id
      ) ;
```

Using `PARTITION`, `1 loops, best of 3: 5.7 s per loop`

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT *,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY keyword_text, keyword_match_type) AS cnt 
    FROM adword_keywords  
    WHERE (keyword_campaign_status, keyword_ad_group_status, keyword_status)
        = ('ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED')
  )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 2 ;
```

Using `GROUP BY` , `1 loops, best of 3: 5.11 s per loop` :

```
select ak.*
from
    adword_keywords ak
    inner join (
        select keyword_text, keyword_match_type
        from adword_keywords
        where
            keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
        group by keyword_text, keyword_match_type
        having count(db_id) > 1
    ) an1 using (keyword_text, keyword_match_type)
    where
            keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to illustrate this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this type of query - so no `COUNT` at all (!), just a check that at least another row exists with same campaign_status and ad_group_status. The check on the primary keys is to ensure just that, that it is another row:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM adword_keywords  
    WHERE (keyword_campaign_status, keyword_ad_group_status, keyword_status)
        = ('ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED')
  )
SELECT a.*
FROM cte AS a
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cte AS b
        WHERE (b.keyword_text, b.keyword_match_type) 
            = (a.keyword_text, a.keyword_match_type)
          AND b.db_id <> a.db_id
      ) ;
```

or window functions:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT *,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY keyword_text, keyword_match_type) AS cnt 
    FROM adword_keywords  
    WHERE (keyword_campaign_status, keyword_ad_group_status, keyword_status)
        = ('ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED')
  )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1 ;
```

---

Your query did not work because you had the ENABLED conditions only in the external level. Adding them into the inetranl (derived table) should give the same results:

```
SELECT ak.*
FROM
    adword_keywords ak
  JOIN
    ( SELECT keyword_text, keyword_match_type
      FROM adword_keywords
      WHERE (keyword_campaign_status, keyword_ad_group_status, keyword_status)
            = ('ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED')
      GROUP BY keyword_text, keyword_match_type
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS d
    USING (keyword_text, keyword_match_type) 
WHERE (ak.keyword_campaign_status, ak.keyword_ad_group_status, ak.keyword_status)
    = ('ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED');
```

Comment: Thanks ! the first version seems to return the correct result: can you please comment on the difference between your query and my query? thanks! in particular I don't see any count >1 parameter in your query, yet the result seems correct

Comment: @Luca your query does not have the `='ENABLED'` conditions in the inner (derived) table. Otherwise it would work as well (What Clodoaldo did but adding the conditions inside, not just moving them. Are you sure that doesn't work?)

Comment: @Clodoaldo Yes what clodoaldo did also returns the wrong number of rows, specifically >> of my original query. While your query returns the correct number < then my original query

Comment: Btw also using window functions, returns the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible that what you want is to place the filter in the counting query?

```
select ak.*
from
    adword_keywords ak
    inner join (
        select keyword_text, keyword_match_type
        from adword_keywords
        where
            keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED' AND
            keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
        group by keyword_text, keyword_match_type
        having count(*) > 1
    ) an1 using (keyword_text, keyword_match_type)
```

Without sample data and desired result it is just a guess

Comment: Returns also the wrong result, many more rows than my original query.

Comment: The ENABLED conditions should be on the external level as well, I think.

Comment: Works if you replicate the 'ENABLED' condition also on the extarnal level as commented by ypercube

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY` some fields, you're doing two important things:

1. You're saying that you want rows where combinations of those fields are distinct.
2. You're saying that all the *other* fields you use, you're going to aggregate.

That "other" might be a problem here.  If you're grouping by a field, you can't decently aggregate that field in the way you want to.

What you could do instead, is count some other field, like your primary key.  (You could also say `COUNT(*)`, i guess -- and in fact, you'd have to if you don't have any unique fields.)

For example, your query could look like

```
SELECT *
FROM adword_keywords
    JOIN (
        SELECT keyword_text keyword_match_type 
        FROM adword_keywords
        GROUP BY keyword_text, keyword_match_type
        HAVING count(keyword_id) > 1
    ) AS duplicated USING (keyword_text, keyword_match_type)
WHERE keyword_campaign_status = 'ENABLED'
  AND keyword_ad_group_status = 'ENABLED'
  AND keyword_status = 'ENABLED'
```

This assumes that you want to find all the records with an "ENABLED" status, where there's at least one duplicate  -- *whether the duplicate is enabled or not*.  If you want only the records that have enabled duplicates, you'd need to add those conditions to the subquery.  (You wouldn't really need them in the outer query at that point, since the inner join would eliminate non-enabled rows.)

For future reference, too:  If you'd rather prevent the duplicates from being in there at all (which is often an error), you might want to consider adding a unique key on `(keyword_text, keyword_match_type)`.

Comment: I got your point however counting the primary key 'db_id' does not seem to make any difference. I have edited the question to provide some example of the data. Also, moving the WHERE clause in the inner select, strangely causes even more rows to be returned ... which is kind of strange since the ENABLED kws are far less than all kws available...